# possibly 'null' and type 'unknown' error typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

hey i have this code below but i get error 'ctx' is possibly 'null'. and 'image' is of type 'unknown'.do you guys know how to solve this error? please tell me how to solve this error

```
export default async function getCroppedImg(imageSrc:any, pixelCrop:any, rotation = 0) {
  const image = await createImage(imageSrc);
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  const maxSize = Math.max(image.width, image.height);
  const safeArea = 2 * ((maxSize / 2) * Math.sqrt(2));

  
  canvas.width = safeArea;
  canvas.height = safeArea;

  
  ctx.translate(safeArea / 2, safeArea / 2);
  ctx.rotate(getRadianAngle(rotation));
  ctx.translate(-safeArea / 2, -safeArea / 2);

  
  ctx.fillStyle = "#DCDCDC";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(
    image,
    safeArea / 2 - image.width * 0.5,
    safeArea / 2 - image.height * 0.5
  );
  const data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, safeArea, safeArea);

  
  canvas.width = pixelCrop.width;
  canvas.height = pixelCrop.height;

  
  ctx.putImageData(
    data,
    Math.round(0 - safeArea / 2 + image.width * 0.5 - pixelCrop.x),
    Math.round(0 - safeArea / 2 + image.height * 0.5 - pixelCrop.y)
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `ctx` might be `null`, is because `canvas.getContext()` might return null. There are two things you can do:

1. Use a guard clause, meaning exit the function if ctx is null:

```
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

if (!ctx) {
  return;
}
```

2. Use the null coalescing operator, meaning everywhere you use `ctx` you check if it exists:

```
ctx?.translate(safeArea / 2, safeArea / 2);
ctx?.rotate(getRadianAngle(rotation));
ctx?.translate(-safeArea / 2, -safeArea / 2);
// etc...
```

For `image`, it is of the type `unknown` because the return value of `createImage()` has this type. You could check if it exists, for example:

```
if (image) {
  ctx.drawImage(
    image,
    safeArea / 2 - image.width * 0.5,
    safeArea / 2 - image.height * 0.5
  );
} else {
  // Handle the case where image is not loaded properly
  console.error('Image could not be loaded');
}
```